# How to show duplicate data one time in drop down list?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am working on a list that get data from database that one teacher can teach many student of one class I want to show that class only one time rather than it show it many time in drop down list as shown below,

[image: enter image d here]

Code of drop down list

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.subject, new SelectList(ViewBag.subject, "CLassSubjectId", "objsub"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Linq query:

```
(from t in db.TeacherEnroll
 from s in db.EnrollInClass.Where(
                                  s => s.BranchClassesId == t.BranchClassesId &&                                      
                                  s.ClassSubject.SubjectId == t.SubjectId && 
                                  t.Teacher.TeacherName.Equals(Currentuser)
                                 )
 select s);
```